# How to remove empty space in table when using rowspan with uneven number of columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to create a table with the first row as parent row with rowspan and other row below as children row. I have provided the example below, could someone please tell me how can I get rid of the empty space in the first row? the empty space will appear if any text inside rowspan is large and aquire more than 1 row. I tried to include 4th td tag in the first row and display:none it, but still did not work.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed;">
<colgroup>
      <col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 40%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 20%; white-space: normal;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
       <col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
    </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
    <th>Random Words</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id='haha'>
  <td rowspan="3">2020</td>
  <td rowspan="3">January</td>
  <td rowspan="3">text in here should be long enough to take more than 1 row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>$200</td>
    <td>There</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: The empty space is there because the second row has only three cells while the first has five. So what do you WANT to be there? Table cells? Then put some in.

Comment: If your question is, "how can I have the cells from the last two rows display higher up", then no, tables can't do that. What you can do is remove the second row and put its three cells in the next one with a rowspan of 2.

Comment: "how can I have the cells from the last two rows display higher up" yes I think I can do that by adjusting position or something. Thanks anyways I will need to construct my table in a different way

Answer (score 0):

### Check if this works for you!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-bordered" style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Year</th>
      <th scope="col">Month</th>
      <th scope="col">Savings</th>
      <th scope="col">Savings for holiday!</th>
      <th scope="col">Random Words</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr id='haha'>
      <td rowspan="2">2020</td>
      <td rowspan="2">January</td>
      <td rowspan="2">text in here should be long enough to take more than 1 row</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>$200</td>
      <td>There</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Try this out on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/richierich25/053kxyts/15/)

Comment: I want the first row act as a parent row, so the structure of my table right now the first row doesn't store any value for the fourth and fifth columns only the children row have it.